# QGIS with MSSQLSpatial : no geometry. OgrInfo Corrupt data

Tags: qgis-3, ogr, sql-server-spatial

I am having this issue while I am trying to connect to my MSSQLSpatial database.

So, I've created this features with just one record with geometry. I can see this feature on Microsoft Management Studio as well on GIS Desktop (Geomedia). My goal is to perform a connection from this database to QGIS. In fact, I can connect all my tables into QGIS  (QGIS version 3.6.0-Noosa) and see their attributes but unfortunately the geometry doesn't show up.

I check the `orginfo` and you may see the logs as the following:

```
ogrinfo -al "MSSQL:server=MYSPATIALSERVENAME;database=MYSPATIALDATABASE;tables=MYTABLE;trusted_connection=yes" -fid 1
```

Result:

```
Layer name: MYTABLE
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 1
ERROR 1: GetNextRawFeature(): Corrupt data
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["NZGD2000 / New Zealand Transverse Mercator 2000",
    GEOGCS["NZGD2000",
        DATUM["New_Zealand_Geodetic_Datum_2000",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6167"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4167"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",173],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",1600000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","2193"]]
FID Column = ID
Geometry Column = Geometry_SPA
Name: String (50.0)
Geometry: Binary (0.0)
ERROR 1: GetNextRawFeature(): Corrupt data
OGRFeature(testFeature):1
  Name (String) = test1
  Geometry (Binary) = C8FFD20FBC8CCF11ABDE08003601B7696898B09D44DA35418295C131AA06534100000000...
```

It shows this error: `ERROR 1: GetNextRawFeature(): Corrupt data`

I also tried with a different table and the same happens. What am I missing here? Why is giving me this corrupt data?

Answer (score 0):

First I'd make sure that the geometry field is valid in SQL Server.  If you already know there's no issue with this you can disregard but it's best to know if it's an issue in sql server first.

Check to see if you can view the geometry in SSMS by select * from yourtable and clicking on the "Spatial Results" tab.  Also in SQL Server run the following query

```
Select geom.STIsValid(), geom.STIsClosed(), geom.STIsSimple()
from yourtable
```

where geom is your geometry field.  If any of these fields returns a 1 let us know.